# How can I give an input field a format?

Tags: javascript, html

Everytime the user presses a button I want every 3 characters to add a dot, example:

```
123
123.456
12.345.678
```

I want this to happend everytime the key is pressed, this is what I have but no luck...

```
function format_num(input) {
    str = input.value;
    str.replace(/(.{3})/,'$1.')
    input.value = str;
}

<input type="text" name="num" id="num" onKeyPress="format_num(this)">
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a very good platform to present javascript code

Comment: One issue is that your replace call will only replace the first occurrence of three characters. If you add the letter g after the second slash, it will replace repeatedly (though that will also give you an extra dot at the end if there is a multiple of 3 characters).

Comment: The title of the question does not correspond to the text of the question. It is also unclear why you would want to do this, i.e. you might be solving the wrong problem. Interfering with user input by automatically inserting characters is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are missing a semicolon after your regex. Second, you have to add the `g` modifier to find all the matches rather than stopping at the first one. Also, assign the result of the `.replace()` to a variable, even `str` itself.

```
str = str.replace(/(.{3})/g,"$1.");
```

This is because in Javascript **strings are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)**: this means that all the `String` method do not actually change the contents string, but return a new *modified* string.

One last caveat: you will notice that, as you add the dots, this regex will not work anymore, as you will be adding dots in between dots.

You have to avoid counting the dots in your string. You might do so by reworking your variable before executing the Regex; something on this line:

```
str = str.split('.').join('');
```

<kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/apobes/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This is the most horrible, unreadable answer I've ever posted but it does work, for any number.

```
var num = 12345678;
var formatted = num.toString().replace(/./g, function(num) { return num+'|'; }).split('|').reverse().join('').replace(/\d{3}/g, function(nums) { return nums+'.'; }).replace(/./g, function(num) { return num+'|'; }).split('|').reverse().join('').replace(/^\./, '');
```

Generates 12.345.678

Comment: Just curious: Can you fix your one-liner for negative numbers?

Comment: Yeap. Just changed the `\d` in the first match to match any character (i.e. also the `-`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to scan from right to left. A more readable (compared to Utkanos) solution is

```
function format_num(input) {
    var inStr = input.value.replace(/\./, '');
    var outStr = '';
    for (var count=0, i=inStr.length-1; i>=0; i--, count++ ) {
        if ( count && count % 3 == 0 ) outStr = '.' + outStr;
        outStr = inStr.charAt(i) + outStr;
    }

    input.value = outStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this script that works perfectly!! I had some issues with the answers so I looked and came up with this piece of work...Thanks anyways!!

```
function formatNumber( originalValue ){

    originalValue = ( originalValue != null ? originalValue.toString() : "0" );

    var nStr = originalValue.replace( /\./g, "" );
    var jj=0;
    var leftNumbers = 0;

    var x = nStr.split(',');
    var x1 = x[ 0 ];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[ 1 ] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    while( rgx.test( x1 ) ){
        x1 = x1.replace( rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
    }

    nStr = x1 + x2;

    for( jj=0; leftNumbers>0; jj++ ){

        if( /[0-9]/.test( nStr.toString().substring( jj, ( jj + 1 ) ) ) )
            leftNumbers--;

    }

    if( originalValue == nStr )
        return originalValue;

    return nStr;
}
```